# Setting :null => false as default behaviour when creating a table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a migration for creating a table with around 15 fields in it and all of them should not be null. I was wondering if is there any trick to do that at once instead of declaring `:null => false` for every single field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can do this using `with_options`. It's most commonly used in routes and setting up validations, but it will actually work on any method that takes an options hash as the last argument. So, something like:

```
create_table :foo do |t| 
  t.with_options :null => false do |opt|
    opt.string :column_name
    opt.string :other_column_name
  end
end
```

Here's the [documentation on Object#with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options).

Comment: Thank you very much Emily. I did not know this.It will help a lot.